# from row to COLUMN addition

Tags: java

this codes print the sum per ROW....
how to convert it so that it will print the sum per COLUMN ?
thanks,,

```
public class NewClass{
  public static void main( String[] arg )
  {
int[][] data = 
    { { 1, 2},
      { 2, 2},
      { 1, 2, 4, 5},
      { 2, 2, 4,},
      { 1, 1, 4, 5 },
      { 2, 1, }};



     for ( int row=0; row < data.length; row++)
        {
           int sum = 0;
          for ( int col=0; col < data[row].length; col++)
          {
           sum = sum + data[row][col];
          }
            System.out.print("Sum of Row " + row+" is :  ");
          System.out.println( sum );
        }         
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take into account that the number of columns in each row is different.

First, you find the maximum number of columns in your data set, then you sum the columns.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        int[][] data = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 2 }, { 1, 2, 4, 5 }, { 2, 2, 4, },
                { 1, 1, 4, 5 }, { 2, 1, } };

        int maxColLength = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
            int colLength = data[row].length;
            if (colLength > maxColLength) {
                maxColLength = colLength;
            }
        }

        for (int col = 0; col < maxColLength; col++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
                if (col < data[row].length) {
                    sum = sum + data[row][col];
                }
            }
            System.out.print("Sum of Column " + col + " is :  ");
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much sir... ah so that's why it stops reading when it reach [0][3], So i must first find the maximum number of column ^__^
thank you very much sir :-)